# React, variable speed Clock with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, settimeout

goal: create a `Clock` component which calls a callback method at regular intervals, but whose speed can be controlled.

Tricky part: do not reset the clock timer immediately when the speed changes, but at the next "tick" check the desired speed and if it has changes, reset the current interval and schedule a new one. This is needed to keep the clock ticket at a smooth pace when changing the speed.

I thought that passing a function `getDelay` that returns the delay (instead of the value of the delay itself) would make this work, but it doesn't.

If I let `useEffect` track the `getDelay` function it will reset when the delay changes. If it don't track `getDelay` the speed will not change while the clock is running.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

type Callback = () => void;

function useInterval(tickCallback: Callback, getDelay: () => number, isPlaying: boolean) {
    const refDelay = useRef<number>(getDelay());

    useEffect(() => {
        let id: number;
        console.log(`run useEffects`);

        function tick() {
            const newDelay = getDelay();
            if (tickCallback) {
                console.log(`newDelay: ${newDelay}`);
                tickCallback();
                if (newDelay !== refDelay.current) {
                    // if delay has changed, clear and schedule new interval
                    console.log(`delay changed. was ${refDelay.current} now is ${newDelay}`)
                    refDelay.current = newDelay;
                    clear();
                    playAndSchedule(newDelay);
                }
            }
        }
        
        /** clear interval, if any */
        function clear() {
            if (id) {
                console.log(`clear ${id}`)
                clearInterval(id);
            }
        }

        /** schedule interval and return cleanup function */
        function playAndSchedule(delay: number) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                id = window.setInterval(tick, delay);
                console.log(`schedule delay id ${id}. ms ${delay}`)
                return clear
            }
        }
        return playAndSchedule(refDelay.current);
    },
        // with getDelay here the clock is reset as soon as the delay value changes
        [isPlaying, getDelay]);
}

type ClockProps = {
    /** true if playing */
    isPlaying: boolean;

    /** return the current notes per minute */
    getNpm: () => number;

    /** function to be executed every tick */
    callback: () => void;
}

export function Clock(props: ClockProps) {
    const { isPlaying, getNpm, callback } = props;

    useInterval(
        callback,
        () => {
            console.log(`compute delay for npm ${getNpm()}`);
            return 60_000 / getNpm();
        },
        isPlaying);

    return (<React.Fragment />);
}
```

Comment: don't use a interval here, but instead check for current time. as the interval can be slowed by javascript execution, so an interval of 1000 can take longer than 1s and the timer will be incorrect.

Comment: @TheWuif That's historically true, but some runtimes (e.g. Chrome) account for the delay and accommodate for the drift. There has even been motion towards standardizing this behavior in the spec: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3151

Comment: @TheWuif, yes I've noticed it's not super reliable. But it's good enough for now. Do you know how to reset the interval only at `tick` times?

Comment: use a `setTimeout` instead of intervall, this will finish and you can use the new delay for the new timeout

Comment: i posted an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';

function useInterval(tickCallback: () => void, delay: number, isPlaying: boolean) {
  const timeout = useRef<any>(null);
  const savedDelay = useRef(delay);
  const savedTickCallback = useRef(tickCallback);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedDelay.current = delay;
  }, [delay])

  useEffect(() => {
    savedTickCallback.current = tickCallback;
  }, [tickCallback])

  const startTimeout = useCallback(() => {
    const delay = savedDelay.current;
    console.log('next delay', delay);
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('delay done', delay);
      savedTickCallback.current();
      startTimeout();
    }, savedDelay.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
      if (isPlaying) {
        if (!timeout.current) {
          startTimeout();
        }
      } else {
        if (timeout.current) {
          clearTimeout(timeout.current);
        }
      }
    },
    [isPlaying, startTimeout],
  );
}

type ClockProps = {
  /** true if playing */
  isPlaying: boolean;

  /** return the current notes per minute */
  getNpm: () => number;

  /** function to be executed every tick */
  callback: () => void;
}

export const Clock: React.FC<ClockProps> = ({ isPlaying, getNpm, callback }) => {

  const delay = useMemo(() => {
    console.log(`compute delay for npm ${getNpm()}`);
    return 60_000 / getNpm();
  }, [getNpm]);

  useInterval(callback, delay, isPlaying);

  return null;
};
```